# Kettle Row Count in Pentaho data Integeration

Tags: pentaho, kettle, pdi

Can any one  please provide an example using which I can COUNT number of rows entered before and after the  transformation \ Job from a table.

Comment: Can you please explain your problem a bit more? Do you want to count the number of rows in a database? Then just use `Execute SQL Script` in a Transformation.

Comment: Yes I want to count number of rows in database before and after data is uploaded. So say if current rows in database are X and I add Y rows to it then Z = X + Y .  I would like to say Job \ transformation was successful if Z > X   or else if Z = X then transformation failed.

Answer (score 1):

- Get the count on table
- Execute your transformation
- Get the count again and use the simple decision step to decide if its a success or not.

This is slightly tricky as you will need to get the count from the table and set it as a variable and then compare variables. Or you can use temp SQL Table for this.